# "Application not found" error while authorizing an org using visual studio code

Tags: salesforcedx, oauth2, visualstudiocode, org, authorization

I am trying to authorize an saleforce org from VS Code using salesforce CLI but I am facing following error "Application not found" (please refer attached screenshot for more details).What should I do?

I have installed all the required salesforce extensions for VS Code i.e (1.Salesforce CLI 2.Salesforce Extension Pack).
I have also installed and configured JDk 11 in case that is required.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you execute the command from cli directly and not from vscode ? This might help narrow the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Chrome as the default browser, in certain scenarios, is not responding in Windows. Try changing to IE/Mozilla temporarily and authorize.

More info here: https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/1654

Comment: Thank you Carlos my default browser was not set as you explained it was the problem (say it was reset)

Comment: Not a problem, mark as answered if possible, then people will be able to see this as an answered question in the future.